# Why is generic of a return type erased when there is an unchecked conversion of a method parameter in Java 8?

Tags: java, generics, java-8

Consider the following code sample:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        String response = getProducer(list).get();
    }
    static Producer<String> getProducer(List<Integer> list) {
        return new Producer<String>();
    }
}
class Producer<T> {
    T get() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

When compiled in Java 7 it just produces an expected warning for `getProducer(list)`:

> Warning:(7, 39) java: unchecked conversion
>   required: `java.util.List<java.lang.Integer>`
>   found:    `java.util.List`

However, when compiled in Java 8 it produces the following error for the `response = getProducer(list).get()` assignment:

> Error:(7, 48) java: incompatible types: `java.lang.Object` cannot be converted to `java.lang.String`

So apparently the type returned from `getProducer(list)` is not `Producer<String>`, but erased `Producer` (which is also confirmed by means of the 'extract variable' feature in the IDE). This is very puzzling because `getProducer` method always returns `Producer<String>`.

Oddly enough it could be fixed by avoiding unchecked conversion while calling `getProducer` method, either by:

- Change parameter type of `getProducer` from `List<Integer>` to `List`
- Change type of `list` variable from `List` to `List<Integer>`

### Updates

- Java used is Oracle JDK 1.8.0_40
- I have also tried using source and target options from 1.5 through 1.7 with the Java 8 compiler and the result was the same.

### Questions

- How could the generic type of the passed **argument** affect a generic type of the method **return value** while the generic type of the return value is fixed in the method signature?
- Why is there such a backward-incompatible change in behavior between Java 7 and Java 8?

Comment: I am using Oracle JDK 1.8.0_40

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I think Oracle is right - once you remove generics everything is erased and Producer.get returns an Object...

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis the op is passing a raw `List` as an argument to the method so I would expect the method signature to be erased. I did not look in details so I may be wrong.

Comment: The lesson? Don't use un-generic types. I imagine the response is something like "Doctor, it hurts when I do this." "Then don't do that!"

Comment: @corsiKa - "But I need to do this for backward compatability!" :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This looks like a known compatibility issue reported [here](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8026329) and [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8-compatibility-guide-2156366.html#A999198).

From the second link:

> The following code which compiled, with warnings, in JDK 7 will not
>   compile in JDK 8:

```
import java.util.List;
class SampleClass {

     static class Baz<T> {
         public static List<Baz<Object>> sampleMethod(Baz<Object> param) {
             return null;
         }
     }

     private static void bar(Baz arg) {
         Baz element = Baz.sampleMethod(arg).get(0);
     }
}
```

> Compiling this code in JDK 8 produces the following error:
>
> SampleClass.java:12: error:incompatible types: Object cannot be
>   converted to Baz
>
> ```
> Baz element = Baz.sampleMethod(arg).get(0);
> ```
>
> Note: SampleClass.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations. Note:
>   Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details. 1 error

Deriving from this, the OP's code can be fixed by replacing this line (the type declartion on the right hand side threw me off - I read it as a typed array list which it is not):

```
List list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

with

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

which will not result in type being being erased from return type of method `getProducer(List<Integer> list)`

Quote from second link again:

> In this example, a raw type is being passed to the
>   `sampleMethod(Baz<Object>)` method which is applicable by subtyping (see
>   the JLS, Java SE 7 Edition, section 15.12.2.2). An unchecked
>   conversion is necessary for the method to be applicable, so its return
>   type is erased (see the JLS, Java SE 7 Edition, section 15.12.2.6). In
>   this case the return type of `sampleMethod(Baz<Object>)` is
>   `java.util.List` instead of `java.util.List<Baz<Object>>` and thus the
>   return type of `get(int)` is `Object`, which is not assignment-compatible
>   with `Baz`.

Comment: You are referring to JLS for Java 7, however the example works in Java 7 and stops working in Java 8. Why is it so?

Comment: @MaxMyslyvtsev its a known published incompatibility - no other reason.

Comment: Seems more like a bug in Java 7 than anything else - the fact that as soon as you mix non-generic and generic you end up with everything being non-generic was already an extended Java puzzler. So it seems like this just used to work due to a bug.

Answer (score 13):

Let’s look into the Java Language Specification:

[Java 8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.6)

> #### 15.12.2.6. Method Invocation Type
>
> …
>
> - If the chosen method is not generic, then:
>
>   - If unchecked conversion was necessary for the method to be applicable, the parameter types of the invocation type are the parameter types of the method's type, and the return type and thrown types are given by the erasures of the return type and thrown types of the method's type.
>
>   …

[Java 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.6)

> #### 15.12.2.6. Method Result and Throws Types
>
> The result type of the chosen method is determined as follows:
>
> - If the chosen method is declared with a return type of void, then the result is void.
> - Otherwise, if unchecked conversion was necessary for the method to be applicable, then the result type is the erasure (§4.6) of the method's declared return type.

It’s important to understand, what “generic method” means:

[Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.4)

> #### 8.4.4. Generic Methods
>
> A method is *generic* if it declares one or more type variables (§4.4).

In other words, the method

```
static Producer<String> getProducer(List<Integer> list)
```

has generic parameter and return types but is *not generic* as it doesn’t declare type variables.

So the cited parts apply, and despite making differences regarding the prerequisites, they agree on the consequences for this specific method invocation, “*if unchecked conversion was necessary for the method to be applicable, then the result type is the erasure … of the method's declared return type*”.

So it’s the older compiler violating the specification by using the return type `Producer<String>` instead of the erasure `Producer`.

Answer (score 3):

The real question is; why can you use raw type?  For backward compatibility.  If it's for backward compatibility, the assumption is only raw types should be used.

> How generic type of passed argument could affect generic type of method return value while generic type of return value is fixed in method signature?

A method or constructor has either of two modes.  It is either completely generic, or it is completely raw typed for backward compatibility.  There is no mode mode of use where it is partly raw typed and partly generic.  The only reason raw types are an option is for backward compatibility and in this situation it assumes all types are/were raw types.

> Why there is such backward incompatible change in behavior between Java7 and Java8?

Since Java 1.4 is not supported any more and hasn't been for a while, the backward compatibility argument doesn't hold as strongly and make some sense to give raw types a place in the current language.

Comment: @AdamSkywalker it working Java 7 because the argument is ignored and it doesn't matter that it's type isn't know.  Change the code to one where the argument is used and it the warning shouldn't be ignored. Java 8 is more pedantic about quite a few things which were just warning in the past. the use of `<p/>` in javadoc is the one which annoys me the most.

Comment: But this would mean that Oracle broke the compatibility? It's hard to believe though

Comment: @AdamSkywalker Oracle do this when they see bad behaviour as they deem it.  They did it a number of ways in Java 8 but in Java 9 there will be much more. e.g. taking away many features they see as unsafe or insecure.

Comment: @AdamSkywalker here is examples of stuff they are taking out. https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/planning_safe_removal_of_under

Answer (score 1):

I guess the reasoning goes like this, focusing on "migration" compatibility -

If the invocation supplies a raw-type argument to a method parameter of a generic-type, it is highly likely that the invocation code is the pre-generic code, and the method declaration, which used to pre-generic too, has since been "evolved" to use generic types.

To maintain perfect compatibility, the fool-proof solution is to erasure the method type, so that it's just like the pre-generic version. This way, the meaning of the invocation stays exactly the same.

A more sophisticated solution might be too complicated for JLS, for example - how do we do type inference if there are raw-type arguments.

---

Today, that assumption may no longer hold- the invocation is more likely a post-generic code, which, for various reasons, still uses raw type nevertheless. It's better to "correct" the raw type early on

```
List list0 = ...; // got it from somewhere, possibly from an old API

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<Integer> list = list0;
```