# Stream works without filter(predicate), gives "Incompatible types" with it

Tags: java, generics, java-stream

Why does the below code work only when the filter-predicate line is commented out. With the filter line, it gives me this error:

```
Incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be converted to java.lang.String
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.joining;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.function.Predicate;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class PredicateStreamInvalidType {
   public static void main(String[] ignored) {

      String input = "one two three four five six seven eight";

      Predicate containsAnE = Pattern.compile("e").asPredicate();

      String[] splits = input.split(" ");

      String output = Arrays.stream(splits).
            //filter(containsAnE).
            collect(joining(" "));

      System.out.println(output);
   }
}
```

I'm expecting this output:

```
one three five seven eight
```

Comment: Why is your `containsAnE` _raw_?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis That's the answer. Post and I'll accept. Learning streams.

Comment: Note that this unrelated to streams and predicates, it's just about generics. Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it).

Comment: Just didn't pay close enough attention to the JavaDoc. I blame streams.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using the raw form of `Predicate<T>` - using raw types is very often where you end up getting compile-time errors involving `Object` where you expected to be using a more specific type.

All you need to do is change the compile-time type of `containsAnE`:

```
Predicate<String> containsAnE = Pattern.compile("e").asPredicate();
```

[`Pattern.asPredicate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#asPredicate--) is declared to return a `Predicate<String>`, so you should be good to go :)

As a way to help you avoid such problems in future, you should see if you can get whatever environment you're using (IDE, command line compilation, whatever) to warn you when you use raw types. It's *almost* always a bad idea.

Comment: My IDE, IntelliJ, did not warn me (no red item on the vertical scroll bar). I thought it was *not* a compile-time error because of it.

Comment: @aliteralmind: It's not a compile-time *error*, but you should examine your IntelliJ settings to see if you can make it at least a *warning*.

Comment: I see. `Preferences > Inspections > Java language level migration aids > Raw use of parameterized class` (on OSX, 14.1). Made a new severity level for it, with a different color, to make it stand out more than regular warnings. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`Arrays.stream(splits)` returns `Stream<String>`

`Stream<String>.filter` method has signature

```
    Stream<String> filter(Predicate<? super String> predicate)
```

this is applicable to the argument `containsAnE`, which is a raw `Predicate`, through an unchecked conversion. Now an interesting thing happens - the return type is erased because of the unchecked conversion! See [this equestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30918308)

Therefore `filter(containsAnE)` returns raw `Stream`.

The instance methods of a raw type are all erased too, therefore the `collect` method signature is

```
    Object collect(Collector collector)
```

This is applicable through subtyping to the argument `joining(" ")` which is a `Collector<CharSequence, ?, String>`. The code compiles so far. But the return type is `Object`.

If you change the the type of `output` variable to `Object`

```
    Object output = Arrays.stream(splits)
        .filter(containsAnE)
        .collect(joining(" "));
```

The code compiles, and runs ... correctly.

That is not an accident; a lot of efforts were made to ensure that pre-generic code works with new generic APIs. That was very important in 2005. Of course, today, we no longer have that concern. **Just don't use raw types**. (unless we have to... in some use cases...)