# Generification of the interface causes compile-error

Tags: java, generics

Java 7

I had an interface:

```
public interface MyInt{
    public Map<String, WhereClause> createClauses(Parameters<Object> params);
}
```

and some its implementation:

```
public class MyImpl implements MyInt{

    @Override
    public Map<String, WhereClause> createClauses(Parameters<Object> p) { //1
        //return some
    }
}
```

Now, I could do with making its return type being generic. I tried this:

```
public interface MyInt <T extends SomeType>{
    public Map<String, ? extends WhereClause> createClauses(Parameters<Object> params);
}
```

But I got compile time error in the implementaiton at `//1`:

```
The method createClauses(Parameters<Object>) of type `MyImpl` must
override or implement a supertype method
```

But when I remove the Generification, the implementation compiles fine.

Why does the generification affect the compilation even in spite of not using of the `type parameter`.

Comment: Do you mean the wildcard (`?`) by "generic"?

Comment: In the new version, are you still writing `public class MyImpl implements MyInt`, or are you writing `implements MyInt<Something>`? If it's the former then the problem is a consequence of the use of the raw type, although I don't claim to understand fully. It works fine if you don't use the raw type `MyInt`.

Comment: @PaulBoddington Yes, it does. But I aws confused by the error. We can use raw-types without any compilation errors... what's wrong?

Comment: @xehpuk No, I meant exactly generic. Because gernefication affects the compilation in my case, not the wildacrdification.

Comment: ? extends WhereClause place this in the interface method and try

Comment: My understanding is that to assist the transition from non-generic code to generic code, they continue to allow raw types. Raw types work by simply ignoring **all** type information for the class, even if appears to have nothing to do with the raw type used (this is the easiest rule to ensure Java 4 code works). Since you use the raw type `MyInt`, the type parameter `<Object>` in the method argument is completely ignored (!), so the method does not override the interface method. I think that's the explanation, but I won't write it as an answer as I'm a bit shaky on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In almost all cases when you find yourself using `?` in generics you are doing it wrong:

```
public interface MyInt<C extends WhereClause> {

    public Map<String, C> createClauses(Parameters<Object> params);
}

private static class MyWhereClause extends WhereClause {

    public MyWhereClause() {
    }
}

public class MyImpl implements MyInt<MyWhereClause> {

    @Override
    public Map<String, MyWhereClause> createClauses(Parameters<Object> p) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds reasonable, actually... Using wildcards doesn't seem good with genereics.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, when an interface is modified in a major way, e.g. changing its type parameters, all subtypes should immediately break, if they are not refactored along.

There is one exception though - if an interface didn't use any generics, we could add generics to it and still keep previously written subtypes compatible. Of course, this is the "migration compatibility". It was a marvel that it worked smoothly; core APIs like `Collection` were generified without breaking old programs. (- here's another language ["feature"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30918308/2158288) intended for keeping migration compatibility)

10 years later, this compatibility feature becomes more and more a curse instead. Your use case looks legit enough, but the language simply didn't envision such cases (i.e. the previous non-generic interface already uses generics signatures), so the behavior seems quite perplexing. There are other puzzlers (and compiler bugs) arising from the same confusion, e.g. what happens to the erasure of a generic type which has a non-generic supertype that has generic method signatures.

At this point, we should simply forget about this feature. Do not try to generify a non-generic interface (unless you can refactor subtypes too). 
Avoid raw types whenever possible.

You could probably introduce a new type, `interface MyInt2<T> extends MyInt`, so that existing subtypes of `MyInt` are not affected.