# How to work around Java generic wildcard limitations

Tags: java, generics, javafx

I came across this problem while trying to iterate over columns of a JavaFX `TableView`. I want to call each column's `cellFactory`, so I did something like this -

```
for (TableColumn<Model, ?> column : getTableView().getColumns()) {
    column.getCellFactory().call(column);
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work, as I get a compilation error:

> incompatible types: javafx.scene.control.TableColumn< Model,capture#1 of ? > cannot be converted to javafx.scene.control.TableColumn< Model,capture#2 of ? >

How can I overcome this? Can I cast the parameter? Introduce explicit type-parameters?

The columns are naturally not all the same type, and I would very much like to avoid having to hard-code the type of every column, as this code should be used for various `TableView`s.

Comment: What is the type of variable `column`?

Comment: It's right there - `TableColumn<Model, ?> column : getTableView().getColumns()`

Comment: Is there anything in the code that does not enable you to extend the TableColumn class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can drop the generics parameter and suppress the rawtypes warning

```
for (@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") TableColumn column : getTableView().getColumns()) {
    column.getCellFactory().call(column); // now compiles
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I was about the mention it. Could you explain why `TableColumn` (with no generic parameter) erases the type of the `Callback` returned?  I would have expected `column.getCellFactory()` to return `Callback<TableColumn, TableCell>` in this case, not `Callback`. Why dropping the inner type necessitates dropping all types under `column` ?

Comment: @sillyfly complicated matter, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30918308/why-is-generic-of-a-return-type-erased-when-there-is-an-unchecked-conversion-of

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to create new class you can use generic static method

```
public static<T> void callCellFactory(TableColumn<Model,T> column){
    column.getCellFactory().call(column);
}
```

Then both column and cellFactory() will be parameterized using same type T.

You will be able to use that function with objects that have wildcard:

```
    for (TableColumn<Model, ?> column : tableView.getColumns()) {
        callCellFactory(column);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to extend the `TableColumn` class, you could add a method that looks something like this:

```
public void callCellFactory() {
    this.getCellFactory().call(this);
}
```

This would enable you to do your call without needing to know the exact class of the second generic. All you instead need to do for each column is to call the non-generic method `callCellFactory()`, and the internal generics of the class will handle the call for you.

Note that you then also need to get an iterable with the new class instead of an iterable of `TableColumn`.

Comment: This feels to me like getting a cannon to squish an ant. Surely there is a simpler solution than introducing new classes? Or is there?